# Merge One CSV file into another

Tags: powershell, csv

I have path1\sample1.csv and path2\sample2.csv file with same column attributes. I need to merge both files with different path into path1\sample1.csv using PowerShell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something like this?

```
Import-CSV path\sample1.csv | Export-CSV path1\sample1.csv
Import-CSV path\sample2.csv | Export-CSV path1\sample1.csv -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Comment: Yes, second commands for me. Thank You for that. 
Can you please help me to remove header from the sameple1.csv using the above command.